# How can two tables be merged (or overlapped) based on values if they fall under a range in R or Excel?

Tags: r, excel-formula

I have two tables, i.e., [Table 1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dp964ft5e3ryj0z/Table%201.csv?dl=0) and [Table 2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6pug0b7t2fkdjz6/Table%202.csv?dl=0) ; I want the names of the traits from Table 1 if the physical position falls in the range (Start_Mb and End_Mb) of Table 2 for each chromosome (1-10). I want traits names in E column of Table 2.

I have tried vlookup function from excel but i did not able to get desire results.

Comment: You have a better chance of getting a response if you `dput()` your data and copy the result into your question. Images of data is discouraged. Thanks

Comment: Perhaps this? https://www.excel-university.com/vlookup-hack-2-range-lookups/

Comment: @LeroyTyrone Thanks for the response. You can download editable Tables through dropbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `relocate()` to order the columns at the end if needed.

```r
library(tidyverse)

table1 <- read_csv("~/Downloads/Table 1.csv")
table2 <- read_csv("~/Downloads/Table 2.csv")

table1 |> 
  select(!QTN) |> 
  right_join(table2, 
             join_by(Chr == CHROM, between(`Physical position of significantly associated SNP`, START_Mb, END_Mb)))
#> # A tibble: 2,468 × 6
#>    Trait       Chr Physical position of…¹ START_Mb END_Mb WEIGHTED_FST/Pi-Rati…²
#>    <chr>     <dbl>                  <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>                  <dbl>
#>  1 KernEar …     2                   17.0     16.4   17.4                   2.34
#>  2 KernEar …     2                   17.0     16.4   17.4                   2.35
#>  3 KernEar …     2                   17.0     16.4   17.4                   2.41
#>  4 KernEar …     2                   17.0     16.4   17.4                   2.40
#>  5 KernEar …     2                   17.0     16.4   17.4                   2.41
#>  6 KernEar …     2                   17.0     16.5   17.4                   2.43
#>  7 KernEar …     2                   17.0     16.5   17.5                   2.42
#>  8 KernEar …     2                   17.0     16.5   17.5                   2.41
#>  9 KernEar …     2                   17.0     16.5   17.5                   2.41
#> 10 KernEar …     2                   17.0     16.5   17.5                   2.41
#> # ℹ 2,458 more rows
#> # ℹ abbreviated names: ¹​`Physical position of significantly associated SNP`,
#> #   ²​`WEIGHTED_FST/Pi-Ratio`
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>